# How do I perform a string replace in batch on %* arguments?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to perform a string replace on the arguments given to my batch file. For example, replacing the `%~dp0` argument from back slashes to forward slashes.

I have tried: `%~dp0:\=/` and `%~dp0:\=/%`, both do not replace the slashes. The only possible solution I can do is messy:

```
set dir=%~dp0
set dir=%dir:\=/%
```

Is there a better way to do it without setting a separate variable and hopefully in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer - No.

String manipulations do not work for parsed arguments (`%1`) or `for` loop tokens (`%%i`).
It is generally considered bad practice to not save your parsed arguments into named variables for two reasons:

**Readability** - transferring your arguments into named variables will increase your ability to debug and understand your code after you have written it.

**Overwriting** - any `call:function param1 param2` occurrences in your scripts will overwrite the argument values within that scope.